# How long can a President's rule be imposed in Maharastra

Tags: india

Since the parties could not form a coalition government, Governor has imposed a President's rule for next six months.

What happens after six months?

As per the numbers it is impossible for the parities to form the government

1. [NCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nationalist_Congress_Party)       -  54
2. [Congress](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_National_Congress)  -  44
3. [Shiv Sena](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shiv_Sena) -  56
4. [BJP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bharatiya_Janata_Party)       - 105

The closest parties that could have come together was BJP and Shiv Sena, since they share the same ideology - [Hindutva](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindutva)

Will there be a re-election in Maharashtra after six months if nobody comes forward to form the government?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If no party/coalition can form a government within this period (ie. President's rule) then the election commission is supposed to conduct fresh elections.
But if the election commission is not able to conduct elections due to any valid reason, the President's rule can be extended with the approval of the Parliament